# Image metadata MediaStore vs. EXIF

Tags: android, exif, mediastore

In Android there seems to be two different way of reading an image's metadata. I know that image's EXIF has data such as timestamp, orientation, gps tag, etc on it, but apparently, you could get the same information through MediaStore, per Android's documentation:
developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html

What's the difference between the two? Can it be safely assumed that data from both will ALWAYS be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the difference between the two?

The `MediaStore` information contains a cached copy of some of that EXIF data, plus other metadata.

> Can it be safely assumed that data from both will ALWAYS be the same?

No. *If* the `MediaStore` is up to date, then yes. However, images are files. Files can be changed. If the `MediaStore` indexes the image file in state A, then something modifies the image file to state B, unless something causes the `MediaStore` to update its cache, they will be out of sync.

Comment: Thanks, so the EXIF will contain the most accurate metadata, correct?

Comment: @baekacaek: That depends upon your definition of "accurate". None of the EXIF metadata is necessarily "accurate". For example, I could geotag a photo as being taken from the top of Mt. Everest, when in reality it was from my patio (nowhere near the Himalayas). Comparing `MediaStore` and EXIF, the EXIF is likely to more up to date. OTOH, querying the `MediaStore` is far more practical than doing a filesystem scan and reading in all the EXIF data yourself. So it all depends on your use case.

Comment: So for writing a gallery app, would reading only the MediaStore suffice for orientation, timestamp, and gps tag? Or would there ever be a situation where an image's metadata on MediaStore is null because it hasn't been cached before?

Comment: @baekacaek: If it hasn't been indexed, you won't find it in `MediaStore`, in which case I have no idea how you are going to find the image to put into your gallery app (again, short of rummaging through directories yourself). Use the `MediaStore` to find image to display. For places where the latest-and-greatest metadata is essential, read the EXIF tags yourself.